dividing screen in 4 parts
I want to display 4 videos on the screen using react, if I increase the size of one video, the others should adjust accordingly , how can I do it?

I tried the following code

<SplitterLayout percentage secondaryInitialSize={50}>
          {/* Left half */}
          <SplitterLayout vertical percentage secondaryInitialSize={50}>
            <div className='bg-red-500 h-full' style={{ padding: '20px' }}>Top Left</div>
            <div className='bg-green-400 h-full' style={{ padding: '20px' }}>Bottom Left</div>
          </SplitterLayout>
          {/* Right half */}
          <SplitterLayout vertical percentage secondaryInitialSize={50}>
            <div className='bg-blue-500 h-full' style={{ padding: '20px' }}>Top Right</div>
            <div className='bg-slate-500 h-full' style={{ padding: '20px' }}>Bottom Right</div>
          </SplitterLayout>
        </SplitterLayout>


You could use flexbox to have a dynamic layout. You can use gap to separate the boxes from each other.


  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
  }

  .container > div {
    flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 20px);
    min-width: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>




got the answer
```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ResizableGrids() {
  const minDimension = 30; // Minimum dimension percentage

  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
topLeftWidth: "50%",
topLeftHeight: "50%",
topRightWidth: "50%",
bottomLeftHeight: "50%",
  });

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const newWidth = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 100;
    const newHeight = (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 100;

    const constrainedWidth = Math.max(minDimension, Math.min(newWidth, 100 - minDimension));
    const constrainedHeight = Math.max(minDimension, Math.min(newHeight, 100 - minDimension));

setDimensions({
  topLeftWidth: `${constrainedWidth}%`,
  topLeftHeight: `${constrainedHeight}%`,
  topRightWidth: `${100 - constrainedWidth}%`,
  bottomLeftHeight: `${100 - constrainedHeight}%`,
});
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
  };

  return (
<div className="relative w-screen h-screen flex flex-wrap">
  <div
    className="absolute z-10 bg-transparent cursor-crosshair"
    style={{
      left: dimensions.topLeftWidth,
      top: dimensions.topLeftHeight,
      width: "20px",
      height: "20px",
    }}
    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
  />

  <div
    className="border border-white flex items-center justify-center"
    style={{
      width: dimensions.topLeftWidth,
      height: dimensions.topLeftHeight,
    }}
  >
    <video
      className="w-full h-full object-fill"
      controls
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    ></video>
  </div>

  <div
    className="border border-white flex items-center justify-center"
    style={{
      width: dimensions.topRightWidth,
      height: dimensions.topLeftHeight,
    }}
  >
    <video
      className="w-full h-full object-fill"
      controls
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    ></video>
  </div>

  <div
    className="border border-white flex items-center justify-center"
    style={{
      width: dimensions.topLeftWidth,
      height: dimensions.bottomLeftHeight,
    }}
  >
    <video
      className="w-full h-full object-fill"
      controls
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    ></video>
  </div>

  <div
    className="border border-white flex items-center justify-center"
    style={{
      width: dimensions.topRightWidth,
      height: dimensions.bottomLeftHeight,
    }}
  >
    <video
      className="w-full h-full object-fill"
      controls
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    ></video>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default ResizableGrids;

```


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
